# Is it possible to auto-upload changed files via SSH?

Tags: ssh

I want to move a file from my computer to another with SSH (that's the only thing I can use, do NOT suggest others).

Currently I move them using pscp, but it's kind of annoying to use.

Is there some sort of hack I could use to achieve this?

The best thing would be having some sort of synced folder that syncs every time a file in there is changed.

Also, if that matters, I use PyCharm (maybe it has a feature for this?), but I am willing to switch IDE if there's this feature.

Comment: Is this coming from a Windows environment? (pscp)

Comment: Can you use `sshfs` - and yes, there are Windows implementations...

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes.

Comment: whatever the final solution (I don't have one), care should be taken to not copy for example a file that was still being written to. it's worse to have something corrupted without knowning it than not having it

Comment: @ivanivan If I understand `sshfs` correctly, If I kill the connection I cant access the data anymore (As I will later detach it from my computer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rsync` to sync your data.

Comment: This might work. I will test it later this week, if I have success, I will select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

rsync can usee SSH as transport and remote shell instead of rsync protocol itself.

As you say being using pscp, I suppose your computer is running on Windows.
If the remote is a Linux host, you could use rsync with SSH.

You can install rsync on Windows using cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/), or (if on Windows 10) using windows sysbsystems for linux (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GwEcijAcW0 ).

Once you have rsync on both sides, you can sync a folder using some command like

```
rsync --rsh=ssh -avz mysource-folder user@remote-host:/path-to-dest-folder
```